Is it possible to make curve be closer to data points?
With ymode=log I'd say it looks somewhat fine, but once set to linear it's quite obvious how far away from the point with highest y value the curve really is. I've tried finding a way to change that behavior, but I haven't found anything useful.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmode=linear,
    ymode=linear,
]
    \addplot +[no marks, gray, raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
       plot '8.3.3.1a.dat' smooth bezier;
       };
    \addplot +[only marks, mark=*, green, mark size=0.3pt, raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
            plot '8.3.3.1a.dat' with points;
        };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Data points:
12000  16.4
13000  20.4
14000  26.4
15000  36
16000  53.6
17000  98
18000  280
18100  296
18200  370
18300  340
19000  162
20000  80
21000  54
22000  42
23000  30
24000  24
25000  22.5



Welcome. // We prefer code, which compiles. A screenshot might help understanding your issue. Thank you

https://i.imgur.com/Ro9LiRq.png
As can be seen on the screenshot the curve goes only to around y = ~260
It's nowhere near the 4 points with highest y values.

Please complete your code fragment so that it makes the image shown (I added it to your question)  you need at least \documentclass and I guess pgfplots

I think your question is more about the mathematics of parameterising curve fitting, rather than typesetting the chosen fit, so it's not clearly on topic (but not clearly off topic either)

Maybe fit a suitable curve to your data instead of using a smoothed curve? A smoothed curve will always have less pronounced features than the original as you are smoothing them out.

It's for an assignment and I was first told to use a smoothed curve and then to make it be closer to those highest y points.
I'm not sure how exactly to go about it. Apparently it's not as easy as I thought it was going to be.
But if it's more of a math problem I guess I'll just pass on it and draw it by hand. I don't really feel like spending more time than necessary trying to grasp math behind a graph that is a part of an assignment, not an assignment in and of itself.

Thanks for the background. However, this is not the place to outsource a task (at least not for free ;-) // Sounds like a task to look into th epgfplots manual, e.g. here https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-patchplots#autosec-9242 , where I searched bezier. Or try smooth as search term

This is typical curve fitting.  Note the points above the line.  I would suggest using a better model than bezier.
